# How to move the Icon to the right

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter and was trying to build a simple UI but encountered a Problem.
I built a AppBar with an Icon inside it. I used the Align Class to move it to the right but it stays at the left side.
Here is my main.dart file:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp (
      home: Scaffold (
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.Right,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screesnshot]

Btw: I know that I should use an IconButton but I tried to build a one page UI and not something with Navigating

Comment: You can add a screenshot for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add icons to the right side of your `AppBar` you can use the `actions` property

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp (
      home: Scaffold (
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.Right,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[ // add the icon to this list
            Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the actions property you can easy put it on the right side.
By default, everything is handled like a leading property
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp(),));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.add)
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```